# How do I create a forest plot of leave one out analysis on metafor?

Tags: metafor, leave-one-out

I was able to obtain the results of leave one out analysis using the command

leave1out(res,transf = exp)

But how do I construct a forest plot from here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started:

```
library(metafor)

dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat <- dat.bcg)

res <- rma(yi, vi, data=dat)
l1o <- leave1out(res)

forest(l1o$estimate, sei=l1o$se, header=TRUE, xlab="Leave One Out Estimate", refline=coef(res))
```

Adjust the look as needed.